What is the correct way to include (CMSIS) header files when using armclang?
I am currently for learning purposes trying to construct a Makefile to understand the building process for embedded programming. I am using the toolchain included in Keil microVision, so my compiler is "armclang".
The Makefile currently looks like this:
arm-toolchain := C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCLANG\bin
export PATH:=$(arm-toolchain);$(PATH)

.PHONY: all
all: object-files

object-files: $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard *.h)
    armclang -c -g  -std=c11 --target=arm-arm-none-eabi $??

I tried reading the armclang documentation to see if there is a way to specify an "include path", but nothing is mentioned in the documentation.
Searching online only yields results for other toolchains, which have different methods.
The only solution that currently comes to mind is just putting all in the include files in the path, but that doesn't seem right.
I was expecting that there would be a clear way of accomplishing this.

From its name, I would take armclang to be a variant of Clang.  The options you are already using in your makefile are consistent with that.  I cannot speak with authority about this particular compiler, but I have good reason to expect that it will accept most or all Clang options, which are mostly a subset of GCC options, including all of the traditional options of Unix C compilers.  Especially -I for adding a directory to the include-file search path.

Hello John, I'd like to accept this as answer, as it solved this for me. I missed in the documentation as my pdf reader only matched the whole word "include" and the relevant page mentioned "included" files only.
Also, the clang documentation reveals that clang and armclang are indeed compatible. I can also use --include-directory=$(inc_cmsis) or something similar.

What documentation are you referring to?  It is clearly documented at https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/0622/armclang-Reference/armclang-Command-line-Options?lang=en (and in the PDF versions included with uVision).

Apparently, armclang is a variant of Clang.  Clang recognizes traditional Unix C compiler options, including in particular -I for adding directories to the include search path.
